# Loop through every row to find if value exists

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have 100 lines of information in SAP GUI and 100 in Excel.

I want to check every line in SAP GUI, to see if that information exists in the 100 lines of information in Excel.

I have the following code, but it does not check through every line, it checks line to line, Example, 10th line in SAP GUI is compared to 10th line in Excel.

```
i = 0
While Cells(7 + i, 1).Value <> ""
    For a = 7 To 100
        If .findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0019/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-EMATN[4,0]").Text = Cells(a, 2).Value Then
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0019/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211").getAbsoluteRow(i).Selected = True
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0019/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211").verticalScrollbar.Position = j
        Else:
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0019/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211").verticalScrollbar.Position = j
        End If
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Next a
    Exit Sub
Wend
```

Comment: Hi. Quick answer but not the best. U have to set to cycle for, first get the line from SAP and then iterate trow all lines of the Excel. Good luck

Comment: what does that `Exit Sub` do inside `While … Wend` loop?

Comment: @DisplayName sorry im bad at coding, but if i rmb correctly, Some people says that exiting a sub is good, guess i put at the wrong location?

Comment: @LuisCurado are you able to show an example if possible?

Comment: `Exit sub` is good if you want to exit the sub. You are exiting the sub after the first iteration of your while loop. I am almost sure that this is not what you want.